# Microsoft Azure service plans

Tags: azure

I am planning to deploy my ASP.NET web app to Azure. So basically, I will be getting an App Service. My question is -- do I also have to get a SQL cloud database service before I can get my app to work? Please shed some light on this issue. And at the very least, how much would be my typical monthly bill?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find out everything you need from the Azure site and related docs and tutorials. Also, there's no way to predict your typical monthly bill - this will be entirely dependent on the services you use, and the service tiers you choose. Unfortunately your question is off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No one here will be able to predict the cost of your usage and services that you will end up using for your app to run properly. Look [azure pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) for this.

As such you have a web app, you will also have a resource group. A resource group is a collection of resources that share the same lifecycle, permissions, and policies.

Now to host your SQL Server database, you have following options below. Wherever you host your database, your web app just needs valid connection string so that it can actually communicate with it.

1. Create a Azure SQL database and configure your web app to communicate with it. Use same resource group as your web app if you would like it to share lifecycle, permissions, policies.
2. Create a Azure VM and install the SQL Server version that you need. There will be templates available with SQL Server installed already. So just roll up a new VM and configure your web app to communicate with it. This may also need a Azure Virtual network (V-NET) setup so that your web app can actually talk to the database as both will run on different machines but can be setup under same resource group. Consider trying [Azure Dev Lab](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/devtest-lab/) templates if you would like to quickly setup a VM with SQL Server on it.
3. If you don't want to pay for azure vm, database, virtual network for your data layer then host your sql server database somewhere else yourself and let your web app communicate with it.

It is down to you really based on your or your client requirements.

Comment: Appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: @gibi Please accept my answer if it actually answers your question. If not, comment below your query and I'll try to solve that too.

Comment: For user who has down-voted my answer: I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use Azure SQL DB's for your environment.  You can deploy a web app without being connected to a DB.  Alternatively, you can run a VM with SQL Server and connected that to your web app if you want.

For the pricing info, Azure has a pretty good calculator to estimate your costs.  That can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/